# Execute a Jupyter notebook from the console

Tags: jupyter

I have some data analysis steps combined in a Jupyter notebook.

As the data change, I want to be able to

1. Re-run all the cells (to take the new data into account)
2. Convert to html for viewing

I know I can do #2 through `jupyter nbconvert`, but how do I do #1 without manually interacting with the notebook web interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nbconvert can do that as well, with the `--execute` argument.

https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-from-the-command-line